# overlay: svg shifts overlay-div, they don't match anymore

Tags: html, css, svg, overlay

I'm totally new here, so I apologize up front if I asked the question wrong or forgot something. I tried things from other questions/answers but nothing could solve my problem.

I have a simple overlay div2 over a div1. The div1 has got an svg inside. The svg pushes the div2 when hovering down so that it doesn't overlap. I want both divs to overlap perfectly sothat the svg of div1 vanishes under div2.

I hope somebody can help me.

Here's the code:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #1b1412;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;  
}

.svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  opacity: 0.9;

}

.div2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 8px;
  opacity:  0.0;
  transition-timing-function:  ease;
  transition-delay:  0.5s;
  transition-duration:  0.5s;
  transition-property:  all;
  -moz-transition-duration:  0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration:  0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:  0.5s; 
}

.div2:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="div1">
  <div class="svg">
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#5b2322;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:18px;}.cls-2{font-size:92px;fill:#d6c9c6;font-family:Alter-Inline-Grunge, Alter Inline Grunge;}.cls-3{letter-spacing:0.04em;}.cls-4{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-5{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-6{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-7{letter-spacing:0.04em;}.cls-8{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-9{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-10{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-11,.cls-13,.cls-14{font-family:Ruthie-Regular, Ruthie;}.cls-12{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-13{font-size:100px;}.cls-13,.cls-14{fill:#9d6763;}.cls-14{font-size:57px;}</style></defs><title>Prospero's Dream</title><polygon class="cls-1" points="311.81 124.73 240.74 42.67 169.67 124.73 98.59 206.78 169.67 288.84 240.74 370.89 311.81 288.84 382.88 206.78 311.81 124.73"/><text class="cls-2" transform="translate(75.9 242.72)"><tspan class="cls-3">P</tspan><tspan class="cls-4" x="35.69" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-5" x="75.71" y="0">o</tspan><tspan class="cls-6" x="112.79" y="0">s</tspan><tspan class="cls-7" x="149.77" y="0">p</tspan><tspan class="cls-8" x="185.47" y="0">e</tspan><tspan class="cls-9" x="222.54" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-10" x="262.56" y="0">o</tspan><tspan class="cls-11" x="294.3" y="0">‘</tspan><tspan class="cls-12" x="309.75" y="0">s</tspan></text><text class="cls-13" transform="translate(141.29 294.74)">Dream</text><text class="cls-14" transform="translate(180.3 173.5)">Lost in</text></svg>
 
  <div class="div2"> 

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to achieve a perfect overlap is to use the `position` property.  To overlap two elements, you:

1. Wrap them in a parent which you make `position: relative`
2. Make the two children `position: absolute`.  Absolute positioning lets you position elements relative to their nearest "positioned parent". This last part is why we made the parent position relative, in step 1.
3. Make sure they are on top of each other using `top: 0`

Demo:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #1b1412;
  margin: 0 auto;  
}

.svg {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  opacity:  0.0;
  transition-timing-function:  ease;
  transition-delay:  0.5s;
  transition-duration:  0.5s;
  transition-property:  all;
  -moz-transition-duration:  0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration:  0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:  0.5s; 
}

.div2:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="div1">
    <svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#5b2322;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:18px;}.cls-2{font-size:92px;fill:#d6c9c6;font-family:Alter-Inline-Grunge, Alter Inline Grunge;}.cls-3{letter-spacing:0.04em;}.cls-4{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-5{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-6{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-7{letter-spacing:0.04em;}.cls-8{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-9{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-10{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-11,.cls-13,.cls-14{font-family:Ruthie-Regular, Ruthie;}.cls-12{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-13{font-size:100px;}.cls-13,.cls-14{fill:#9d6763;}.cls-14{font-size:57px;}</style></defs><title>Prospero's Dream</title><polygon class="cls-1" points="311.81 124.73 240.74 42.67 169.67 124.73 98.59 206.78 169.67 288.84 240.74 370.89 311.81 288.84 382.88 206.78 311.81 124.73"/><text class="cls-2" transform="translate(75.9 242.72)"><tspan class="cls-3">P</tspan><tspan class="cls-4" x="35.69" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-5" x="75.71" y="0">o</tspan><tspan class="cls-6" x="112.79" y="0">s</tspan><tspan class="cls-7" x="149.77" y="0">p</tspan><tspan class="cls-8" x="185.47" y="0">e</tspan><tspan class="cls-9" x="222.54" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-10" x="262.56" y="0">o</tspan><tspan class="cls-11" x="294.3" y="0">‘</tspan><tspan class="cls-12" x="309.75" y="0">s</tspan></text><text class="cls-13" transform="translate(141.29 294.74)">Dream</text><text class="cls-14" transform="translate(180.3 173.5)">Lost in</text></svg>
  </div>

  <div class="div2"> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I had to fiddle around a bit with my code, but it works now! :-) Only problem I now have: I cannot center-align the whole div, even if I put another div around to have the align-command put there.

Comment: Using an outer container works. See: http://jsfiddle.net/8vs65gaq/3/  Or as an alternative, you could use the left+transform trick: http://jsfiddle.net/8vs65gaq/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! The outer container didn't work (and I couldn't understand how, anyway), but the second trick did.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to overlap the 2nd div on top of the 1st div on hover you can just hide the 1st div and show the 2nd one to achieve the same effect. Snippet:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #1b1412;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;  
}

.svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.container:hover .svg {
  display: none;
}

.div2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-delay:  0.5s;
  transition-duration:  0.5s;
  transition-property:  all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">

<div class="svg">
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#5b2322;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:18px;}.cls-2{font-size:92px;fill:#d6c9c6;font-family:Alter-Inline-Grunge, Alter Inline Grunge;}.cls-3{letter-spacing:0.04em;}.cls-4{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-5{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-6{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-7{letter-spacing:0.04em;}.cls-8{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-9{letter-spacing:0.06em;}.cls-10{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-11,.cls-13,.cls-14{font-family:Ruthie-Regular, Ruthie;}.cls-12{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-13{font-size:100px;}.cls-13,.cls-14{fill:#9d6763;}.cls-14{font-size:57px;}</style></defs><title>Prospero's Dream</title><polygon class="cls-1" points="311.81 124.73 240.74 42.67 169.67 124.73 98.59 206.78 169.67 288.84 240.74 370.89 311.81 288.84 382.88 206.78 311.81 124.73"/><text class="cls-2" transform="translate(75.9 242.72)"><tspan class="cls-3">P</tspan><tspan class="cls-4" x="35.69" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-5" x="75.71" y="0">o</tspan><tspan class="cls-6" x="112.79" y="0">s</tspan><tspan class="cls-7" x="149.77" y="0">p</tspan><tspan class="cls-8" x="185.47" y="0">e</tspan><tspan class="cls-9" x="222.54" y="0">r</tspan><tspan class="cls-10" x="262.56" y="0">o</tspan><tspan class="cls-11" x="294.3" y="0">‘</tspan><tspan class="cls-12" x="309.75" y="0">s</tspan></text><text class="cls-13" transform="translate(141.29 294.74)">Dream</text><text class="cls-14" transform="translate(180.3 173.5)">Lost in</text>
</svg>
</div>
 
<div class="div2"> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this one but 1) the div2 is stuck beneath div1 when I don't hover. And 2) when I tried to hover it glitches constantly.